# Delete all app's preferences on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I installed an app, watched its intro slider and tapped signup with a certain social media, which shared my email. Before continuing to accept the terms, I decided to backtrack of sharing my email, so I deleted the app and reinstalled it. It still starts at the screen *after* the social signup, asking me to accept the terms. I went to settings, iPhone storage and used "delete app" which says "this will delete the app and all related data from the iPhone". Alas, after reinstall, it still goes directly to the terms. I also checked in the iCloud settings and the app is not listed.

How do I make my iPhone / account entirely remove the data stored by this app?

Comment: The developer is storing your device's unique identifier on their servers, not your device. When you try to sign up again, the developer recognizes your device and progress then places you back where you left off. Try turning off wifi/cell and try the installation again.

Comment: @fsb turning off wifi, airplane more and restarting the device didn't help. Storing my data and especially connected to my device's data before consenting to terms and privacy seems malpractice. So I think I'll just pass on this app.

Comment: They're not storing your data, they can't. Apple's sandboxing of app data doesn't allow this. When you uninstall an app, assuming you don't have any other apps from the same developer, it deletes all the app data. Something else is going on here.

Comment: @fsb what I meant is that they are storing my data on their server, as you suggested in your first comment.